# FPC IDE: Can't find unit system

Tags: freepascal

I just installed FPC 3.2.0 (on Linux Mint 19.3) and trying to use FPC IDE. I launched the IDE from the `bin` installation subfolder as `./fp`, written a simplest program in IDE

```
program hello;

begin
  writeln('hello');
end.
```

saved the program as `hello.pas` and when I compile it I get

```
(3,1) Fatal: Can't find unit system used by hello
(0) Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

This is strange because `system` is the compiler's unit, not a user's unit.

I tried to google the issue, found several posts in different forums, one question was dated back to 2007 year, and **none** of the questions was answered.

Is where a way to solve the issue or FPC IDE is dead for about 15 years?

Answer (score 5):

Check the unit directories in options->directories -> unit directories.

The package configuration should have put a line like

/usr/lib/fpc/$FPCVERSION/units/$FPCTARGET/*

The dollar values are builtins (respectively 3.2.0  and  i386-linux or x86_64-linux). Please verify that the directories with prebuilt .ppu .o are there.

Comment: Thanks, but I removed FPC already and installed Lazarus 2.0.10 which is built on the same FPC 3.2.0, and FPC IDE works on Lazarus installation as expected. How to make FPC IDE work on a clean FPC installation remained a mystery to me.

Comment: It works fine on Windows where the circumstances are pretty constant, and the FPC team does the packaging. On Linux we depend on the distribution maintainers to do this, and IMHO (Linux) distribution packages of FPC are much less ready to run.

Comment: Paths may differ on different systems. On Ubuntu 20.04 it is


/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fpc/$fpcversion/units/$fpctarget/*

Comment: That's an ubuntu/debian invention then.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix your installation of FPC or you can fix it manually by calling fpcmkcfg

fpcmkcfg -d "basepath=path/to/fpc/3.3" -o path/to/fpc.cfg

> For instance, if the compiler is in /usr/local/bin, it will look in
> /usr/local/etc.

Comment: This worked for me, once I realized that 'fpcmkcfg' on Debian, for example, is '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-fpcmkcfg-3.2.0'.  I used the system fpc.cfg: /etc/fpc.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04. To solve it, I had to create the file **fp.cfg** in my project's folder with the following content:

```
-Fu/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fpc/$fpcversion/units/$fpctarget
-Fu/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fpc/$fpcversion/units/$fpctarget/*
```

If this will not work, it means unit path on your system is different. You may use something like

```
dpkg -L fp-units-base-3.0.4 | grep .ppu
```

to find out where units are actually stored. Replace 3.0.4 with your actual Free Pascal version. If you do not know exact version, use

```
sudo apt install apt-show-versions
apt-show-versions fpc
```

It will show something like

```
fpc:all/focal 3.0.4+dfsg-23 uptodate
```

3.0.4 is the version number you need.

Another way of getting needed paths is running this command:

```
cat /etc/fpc.cfg | grep -- -Fu | head -2
```

So you may just run

```
cat /etc/fpc.cfg | grep -- -Fu | head -2 > fp.cfg
```

in your project's folder to have the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

- How to use `Free Pascal` (`Lazarus`) on `Linux` - *no install* solution:

1. If not already installed, install "GNU binutils" (required in order to be able to compile Pascal programs (*.pas* extension)) ( can be installed with: `sudo apt-get install binutils` )
2. Dowload the latest version of `Free Pascal` (`Lazarus`): from the [Downloads](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloads) section of the [Lazarus Home page](https://www.lazarus-ide.org) (*Lazarus* is a professional open-source cross platform IDE powered by *Free Pascal*):

   2.1. In case of a `Debian` based Linux system (such as `Ubuntu`): the `.deb` package could be downloaded ("`fpc-laz_<version> ... .deb`" (replace `<version>` with an actual version number))

   2.2. In case of a `RPM` based Linux system (such as `Fedora`): the `.rpm` package could be downloaded ("`fpc-<version> ... .rpm`" (replace `<version>` with an actual version number))
3. Extract the downloaded package:

   3.1. Place the downloaded `.deb` / `.rpm` package in the folder where you are going to extract it

   3.2. Extract the downloaded `.deb` / `.rpm` package by *Right-Click*-ing it and then choosing *Extract Here*

   3.3. In the case of a `.deb` package: open the extracted "`usr`" folder and extract "`data.tar.xz`" - by *Right-Click*-ing it and then choosing *Extract Here*

   3.4. Move the extracted "`usr`" folder, in the desired folder location - for example create a folder named "*fpc*" in the desired location and move the "`usr`" folder in there; Further we denote this folder (e.g. "*fpc*") as: "`<BASEFOLDER>`" and its path as: "`<BASEFOLDER_PATH>`"
4. *** In the terminal: change the working directory to the desired directory (this is where the Pascal configuration files and Pascal programs (*.pas* extension) will be saved) -> please note that the working directory should be set correctly before each time the *fp* binary is launched from the terminal (see step 5. bellow)
5. *** Launch the `Free Pascal` binary by running the next command in the terminal:

   `<BASEFOLDER_PATH>/usr/bin/fp`
6. To add the units folders: From the `Free Pascal` Menu, access: `Options` -> `Directories` -> and copy and paste (`CTRL + C` to Copy from outside the IDE, and `(FN + )SHIFT + Insert` to Paste inside the IDE) to the "`Units`" tab, the next three lines, each on a new line (replace `<BASEFOLDER_PATH>` with its corresponding value; replace `<LIB_FOLDER>` with its corresponding value: for example *`lib`* in case of a `.deb` package, or *`lib64`* in case of a `.rpm` package):

   `<BASEFOLDER_PATH>/usr/<LIB_FOLDER>/fpc/$fpcversion\units\$fpctarget`

   `<BASEFOLDER_PATH>/usr/<LIB_FOLDER>/fpc/$fpcversion\units\$fpctarget\*`

   `<BASEFOLDER_PATH>/usr/<LIB_FOLDER>/fpc/$fpcversion\units\$fpctarget\rtl`
7. Please note that by moving the files in the `<BASEFOLDER>` directory to other `<BASEFOLDER>` directory, you'll have to update the above three lines so that they contain the new `<BASEFOLDER_PATH>`, otherwise you might get errors like:

   "`Fatal: Can't find unit ...`"
8. For navigation inside the IDE using keyboard - the following shortcuts could be used: `Alt + Highlighted-letter, Highlighted-letter(s)`, `Tab` / `Shift + Tab`, `Arrows`, `Enter`, `Esc`
9. For Official *Online Documentation* see:

   [Online Documentation](https://www.freepascal.org/docs.html)